# Projection and Reflection matrices in different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

> Given a plane $\pi=span(v,w)$ where $v=(3,-2,6)$ and $w=(3,5,-8)$. We have constructed orthonormal basis $B=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ such that $\pi=span(u_1,u_2)$ and $u_3$ is normal to the plane.
> Using the basis $B=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ determine the matrices $P$ and $R$ which represents the projection onto $\pi$ and reflection across $\pi$. Then also using the standard basis $E=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ determine the matrices $Q$ and $S$ which represents the projection onto $\pi$ and reflection across $\pi$.

What I do know is

$u_1=\frac{1}{7}(3,-2,6),u_2=\frac{1}{7}(6,3,-2),u_3=\frac{1}{7}(-2,6,3)$

Let $O=\dfrac{1}{7}\begin{bmatrix}3&6\\-2&3\\6&-2\end{bmatrix}$ and the projection onto $\pi$ is given by $O(O^TO)^{-1}O^T=\dfrac{1}{49}\begin{bmatrix}45&12&6\\12&13&-18\\6&-18&40\end{bmatrix}$
and reflection across $\pi$ is given by $I-2u_3u_3^T=\dfrac{1}{49}\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}{41} & {24} & {12} \\ {24} & -{23} & -{36} \\ {12} & -{36} & {31} \\ \end{array} \right]$

I think these are in standard basis, right ?

How do I determine the matrices in both bases without using the transition matrix ?

Comment: Hint: every point in $\pi$ has a $u_3$ coordinate of ... So if I want to project a point onto $\pi$ I simply set its $u_3$ coordinate to ... and leave the other two coordinates ...

Comment: @NeitherNor Okay, so the projection matrix in terms of $u_1,u_2,u_3$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, right ?

Comment: Correct! Can you also also guess the reflection matrix?

Comment: @NeitherNor \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix} right ?

Comment: Great! And now, make a coordinate transformation back to the standard basis!

Comment: as simple as that right. But when I looked at the problem I got really confused, Thanks.